# Replicate updated jar file to each slave node on Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing, replication

I have an Apache Spark cluster consisting of a master and multiple slave nodes. In the jars folder of each node I require the jar file for a program I run on Spark.

There are regular updates to this jar so I find myself constantly copying the updated jar file.

Is there a quick and easy way that an updated jar file can be replicated from master to all slave nodes or any other way of distributing this each time the jar is updated?

Comment: If you shade that JAR file's classes into the `spark-submit` running JAR file, you wouldn't need to deploy it separately

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks for the reply. Please seem my comment to a similar response in the answer below.

Comment: Your JAR needs transfered to the cluster no matter what. Whether it's part of your code, or in HDFS/some shared filesystem. Point being,  it would need copied to each executor's memory space. Doing that manually yourself doesn't scale well

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean by "transfered to the cluster". Does this mean that a copy of the jar must be on the master and each slave node? If I have the jar on my master and run spark-submit I can see that the slave nodes seem to work as expected but I can't see any evidence of the jar having been copied from master to the slaves.

Comment: It is. Spark distributes the code for you. How else would it actually run?

Comment: And master/slaves is a different terminology than driver/executor, which is what I'm referring to

Comment: Thanks just wanted to be sure. My last query with this is that if the jar is already on the slave nodes will spark know that it doesn't need to distribute the code on spark-submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you running your Spark job with spark-submit use `--jars` option. Using this option you can write path to jar file that you need.
Also, jars in `--jars` option will be automatically transferred to the cluster, so you need this jar only on the master node.
Read about how to use this option [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management).

Comment: Thanks. Thats how I was originally working but I believe there is a performance hit when transerring the jar to the cluster. I'm trying to avoid this so would like to have the jar on each cluster before spark-submit is ever executed.

Comment: Maybe you can put the jar to hdfs and executors will take it from there?